# Inherit from a class that has a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a class with a generic type

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : new()
{
    public T GenericType;

    public GenericClass()
    {
        GenericType = new T();
    }
}
```

I now want to create new classes that inherit from my GenericClass but passing the new class in as the type.

so...

```
class Class1:GenericClass<Class1>
{
    public string Class1Property { get; set; }
}

class Class2 : GenericClass<Class2>
{
    public string Class2Property { get; set; }
}
```

If I do this and then create a new instance of Class 1 the code goes into an infinite loop.

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Well, what _are_ you trying to do?  Did you mean to store just the _type_ of `T` rather than an _instance_ of `T`?

Comment: `class Class1:GenericClass<Class1>` is an infinite loop as you found out, what did you expect it to do?

Comment: You could also check if `typeof(T) == typeof(this)` to avoid the infinite loop but it's not clear at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RonBeyer The line that you've showed doesn't necessarily create an infinite loop.  It's a constructor constructing an instance of the type currently being constructed that creates the infinite recursion.  A type inheriting from a generic type with itself as the generic argument happens all the time, and is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Servy yes, I meant in the context of his generic parent type. If he didn't have the `new T()` in there, it wouldn't create a loop. I understand that I'm just trying to find out what the intent was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line of

```
GenericType = new T();
```

in your base constructor is calling the constructor for the inheriting type, which calls the base constructor, which continues the loop.

If you are just trying to track the type of the class that inherited, try a

```
typeof(T);
```

or

```
this.GetType();
```

as they get you the type, without creating a new instance of the type.